# How to set backgroundSize property to default in jquery?

Tags: jquery, background, size

Actually I wanna animate background image. So what i did is, when div his hovered, the background image hides gradually.

```
$(this).animate({ backgroundSize: '0%', opacity: 0}, 500)
```

Now when div is not hovered, i want to set backgroundSize to default value.. like

```
$(this).animate({backgroundSize: 'auto', opacity: 1}, 500)
```

But it didnt work.

In Css div class is like...

```
.divImg{ background: url(../imgs/bgImg.png) no-repeat center; background-size: auto }
```

What i want is when div is not hovered background image should come back to its default size and position.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `!important`:

```
  $(this).animate({backgroundSize: 'auto !important', opacity: 1}, 500)
```

**Edit**: Updated code to match the example in the question.

Comment: No, I want to do it using jQuery.

Comment: Sure you can do that. Just add the '!important' to your backgroundSize value. I've updated my post to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

i am not 100% sure abut this, but i believe jquery .animate() can only animate number based properties. my guess is that trying to make "100%" change to 'auto' might be the problem.

try only animating the opacity, and change to 'auto' with the .css() function, after a timeout, if you need it.